# Drupal 8 + NodeJS connected but notification is not showing on frontend

Tags: node.js, notifications, drupal-8, notify

I have successfully installed and configured the Drupal 8 with NodeJS module.

Since Nodejs Notifcations module (nodejs_notify) is enabled, I tried to broadcast a message. What do I get? Total silence. No notifications anywhere. This is what the terminal shows:

```
[2017/09/21 16:43:45] Route callback: checkServiceKey
[2017/09/21 16:43:45] Route callback: publishMessage
[2017/09/21 16:43:45] Body
{ broadcast: true,
  data: { subject: 'hey ', body: 'hey' },
  channel: 'nodejs_notify' }
[2017/09/21 16:43:45] broadcastMessage
{ broadcast: true,
  data: { subject: 'hey ', body: 'hey' },
  channel: 'nodejs_notify' }
```

Here is my configuration setting :

```
settings = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8888,
  host: 'localhost',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: 'test',
  backend: {
    port: 80,
    host: '178.62.13.67',
    scheme: 'http',
    basePath: '',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: true,
  sslKeyPath: '',
  sslCertPath: '',
  sslCAPath: '',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};
```

Do I need to install any notification kind of plugin in Drupal 8?

What type of notification it will be? I assume HTML 5 Push Notification popup on browser.

Is there anything I am missing?

I tried creating other users and on checked on different computers but no luck. No notification. Total silence.

It is driving me crazy.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share you console window from browser. It should be telling the exact issue. Mine was socket.io path & port issue. Make sure you have properly configured base path & ports.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with nodejs & drupal 8. I finally managed to make it work. This is how I could do it:

There were 2 parts to the solution.

Problem 1. Initially, the error was that the app was showing invalid token error.
Solution:- Keys in settings json need to be in double quotes as follows.

```
settings = {
  "scheme": "http",
  "port": 8080,
  "host": "",
  "resource": "socket.io",
  "serviceKey": "AS GIVEN IN DRUPAL NODEJS SETTINGS",
  "backend": {
    "port": 80,
    "host": "myhost.dev",
    "scheme": "http",
    "basePath": "",
    "messagePath": "/nodejs/message"
  },
  "debug": true,
  "sslKeyPath": "",
  "sslCertPath": "",
  "sslCAPath": "",
  "baseAuthPath": "/nodejs/",
  "extensions": [],
  "clientsCanWriteToChannels": false,
  "clientsCanWriteToClients": false,
  "transports": ["websocket", "polling"],
  "jsMinification": true,
  "jsEtag": true,
  "logLevel": 1
};
```

Problem 2: Drupal could connect to server, but notification still not working.

My solution that worked:

The issue seemed to be in the function `safeNodeServerVerion()` of Nodejs Class inside Nodejs.php file. I changed the last line as follows:

```
/** This was the original line **/
return $this->nodeServerVersion && $this->nodeServerVersion >= self::SAFE_NODE_SERVER_VERSION;
```

The comparison of node versions, were not working as expected.

I removed the '.' in the version strings, casted them as integers, and then compared. It seems to work fine for me now.

Working code:

```
$node_ver = (int)str_replace('.', '', $this->nodeServerVersion);
$safe_node_ver = (int)str_replace('.', '', self::SAFE_NODE_SERVER_VERSION);
return $this->nodeServerVersion && $node_ver >= $safe_node_ver;
```

Hope this helps someone. Cheers.